# Migrated WP site -> "critical error"

Tags: wordpress, migration

I'm trying to migrate my site from Bluehost to Cloudways hosting. The migration goes thorough successfully, but when I try to access the WordPress Admin (/wp-admin) I get "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I have tried deleting the migrated site and starting over. I have tried renaming the "plugins" folder to disable everything - it all works until I activate CiviCRM. I tried deleting all the CiviCRM files and installing the plugin from a fresh download. Still getting the same error caused by the CiviCRM plugin.

Obviously, this plugin is essential to my site, so hopefully someone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: What does the email in the site admin mailbox say? Otherwise you'll need to look in the web server log (e.g. apache log) and it will tell you the error - it's likely that a system requirement is missing on the new server, e.g. https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#required-for-civicrm-core

Comment: Usually when I get these kinds of errors, I contact my host to help go through the logs and find out what is causing it. You may be missing a requirement, need an action whitelisted, etc. Almost every time I've found it was something that I needed my host's help on.

Comment: @Demerit there actually wasn't any email in the site admin box at all, I checked spam and another email also, nothing. But thank you for that requirements list link!

Comment: Thank you @JenniSimonis for the suggestion of contacting my host - I will do that, and with the list of requirements, hopefully they can fix it!

Comment: No problem. I never get those emails, either.

Comment: Can you confirm if the instructions here were followed? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: Thank you @petednz-fuzion for that link! Unfortunately those instructions don't really seem to be written for WordPress, so I tried to follow the parts that were labeled for WP, but no success. I've been in contact with my host and they say everything is installed on their end, so it must be a plugin issue. I have a feeling these instructions are the key, but I'm just not sure how to follow them :(

Comment: you may want to ask at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress as more likely you will get some step by step help to decipher the documentation (and help improve it if you think it needs it)

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP?

Have you tried removing all of the civicrm extensions?

You say you have the issue with a fresh install... if all of the requirement checks pass on the installer page: https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/
... then that would also point to extensions being the culprit.

Comment: Check the Cloudways hosting to ensure you have the required php extensions https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/